# Why is Eclipse's Android Device Chooser showing a fake emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have no open emulator and no device connected to my computer but when I run my android project it shows me the following emulator. Why?

I have restarted my eclipse and my computer. nothing changed.

[image]

Comment: are you install blueStacks?

Comment: @HamidrezaSamadi Oh. Yes. Can I do something to remove it from android chooser?

Comment: if blueStacks be opened you can use it as an emulator. but you can remove it from emulators list by closing it from bottom and right of screen. excuse me for bad english.

Comment: @HamidrezaSamadi ممنون آقا اشکال نداره.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By any chance do you have an application installed called **BlueStacks**? If the answer is yes then this is because this is its self an Android emulator which listens on port 5554